# Subtract values from sum query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query to group items in collection month-by-month but I want it to return results adaptable to stack(grouped) bar charts on Grafana dashboard.

Here's the full query;

```
db.scheduler.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "payload.result.eventTimeMs": {
            "$gt": 0,
            "$lt": 1610005867604
        },
        "payload.result.status": {
            "$in": ["breach","success"]
        }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$concat": [{
                "$substr": [{
                    "$year": {
                        "$add": [{
                            "$dateFromString": {
                                "dateString": "1970-01-01"
                            }
                        },
                        "$payload.result.eventTimeMs"]
                    }
                },
                0,
                4]
            },
            "-",
            {
                "$cond": [{
                    "$lte": [{
                        "$month": {
                            "$add": [{
                                "$dateFromString": {
                                    "dateString": "1970-01-01"
                                }
                            },
                            "$payload.result.eventTimeMs"]
                        }
                    },
                    9]
                },
                {
                    "$concat": ["0",
                    {
                        "$substr": [{
                            "$month": {
                                "$add": [{
                                    "$dateFromString": {
                                        "dateString": "1970-01-01"
                                    }
                                },
                                "$payload.result.eventTimeMs"]
                            }
                        },
                        0,
                        2]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "$substr": [{
                        "$month": {
                            "$add": [{
                                "$dateFromString": {
                                    "dateString": "1970-01-01"
                                }
                            },
                            "$payload.result.eventTimeMs"]
                        }
                    },
                    0,
                    2]
                }]
            }]
        },
        "breach-ayliktoplam": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$payload.result.status", "breach" ] },
                    1, 
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "success-ayliktoplam": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$payload.result.status", "success"] },
                    1, 
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "_id": 1
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "name": "$_id",
        "value": { "$subtract": [ "$breach-ayliktoplam", "$success-ayliktoplam" ] },
        "ts": {
            "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": "2020-01-01"
            }
        },
        "_id": 0
    }
}],
{
    "allowDiskUse": true
});
```

And its results are like this;

```
{"name":"2019-01","value":21,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-02","value":20,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-03","value":18,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-04","value":5,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-05","value":27,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-06","value":34,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-07","value":31,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-08","value":47,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-09","value":46,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-10","value":48,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-11","value":42,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-12","value":63,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-01","value":-18,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-02","value":-3,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-03","value":90321,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-04","value":-63,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-05","value":11,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-06","value":57,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-07","value":-17,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-08","value":78167,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-09","value":130,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-10","value":6,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-11","value":11,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2020-12","value":31,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2021-01","value":1,"ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
```

What I need is to substract this **breach-ayliktoplam** and **success-ayliktoplam** in two different results. Here's what I want;

```
{"name":"2019-01","value":21,"status":"breach","ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-01","value":34,"status":"success","ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-02","value":20,"status":"breach","ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
{"name":"2019-02","value":20,"status":"success","ts":{"$date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
.........
```

One of the results represent **breach-ayliktoplam** and other one is **success-ayliktoplam** with the help of **status** field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you try do to, but I guess it would be simply

```
{
   $group: {
      _id: {
         $dateFromParts: {
            year: { $year: "$ts" }, month: { $month: "$ts" }
         }
      },
      "success-ayliktoplam": { $sum: ...}
   }
}
```

Comment: With your advice, I get one result. I wrote the format I want it to return. It should be month-by-month like I wrote

Comment: Then add `$status` to the `_id` field